# Python: Comparing two strings that are not exact match

Tags: python

I would like to compare two strings in Python, where:

```
string1 = 'yymm_employeenumber_Employee Name' 
# Example: 2203_1145_John Doe

string2 = 'employeenumber_Employee Name'
# Example: 1145_John Doe
```

How can I ignore the the **yymm_** characters in string1 and the space in Employee Name?

Comment: Identify which format the string is using, and save that into a data structure (e.g. dictionary or dataclass), then compare.

Comment: Is this logic part of a larger project or is this just an exercise? If it's part of a larger project, then this way of storing data is not a good idea. In Python, it'll be better to use tuples or even a class where the date, employee number, and employee name is all separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cases like these, it's usually best to define a custom class that can handle comparisons, i.e. something like this:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, yymm, employee_number, employee_name):
        self.yymm = yymm
        self.employee_number = employee_number
        self.employee_name = employee_name
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.yymm:
            return f"{self.yymm}_{self.employee_number}_{self.employee_name}"
        return f"{self.employee_number}_{self.employee_name}"
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Since we are ignoring yymm, don't compare it in eq
        return self.employee_number == other.employee_number and self.employee_name == other.employee_name
        
employee1 = Employee("2203", "1145", "John Doe")
employee2 = Employee(None, "1145", "John Doe")
print(employee1 == employee2)
print(employee1)
print(employee2)
```

The output of this would be

```
True
2203_1145_John Doe
1145_John Doe
```

If you really need to decode the class from a string representation, you can add the following method:

```
def load_from_string(employee_string):
    # Assuming the format is always yymm_number_name OR number_name
    # If it's not, this doesn't work
    split_string = employee_string.split("_")
    if len(split_string) == 2:
        return Employee(None, split_string[0], split_string[1])
    return Employee(split_string[0], split_string[1], split_string[2])
```

Then running

```
employee1 = load_from_string("2203_1145_John Doe")
employee2 = load_from_string("1145_John Doe")

print(employee1 == employee2)
print(employee1)
print(employee2)
```

Would return

```
True
2203_1145_John Doe
1145_John Doe
```

In any case, the class should be used.